# How to Upload Video on Facebook user wall in iOS 6 in XCode 4.5?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6, xcode4.5

I am trying to upload video on facebook wall using this tutorial [Link](https://bitbucket.org/danielphillips/fb-video-upload) .when i run this tutorial source code in Xcode 4.5 it gives me the following Error

'`FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h`'

File not found

Can some guide me how we can fix this error .Thanks

Comment: Download SDK from facebook developer website.

Comment: Link Available for below. thanks

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

Comment: Have you please checked the source code there for yourself beacause after adding the sdk it successfully loging to facebook but did not upload video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Following Things:

1. Add FacebookSDK.Framework or FBiOSSDK.Framework

   [Link For SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/)
2. Import FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h
3. Verify the Framework in Added in Build Phases.

Answer (score 3):

Have you included FacebookSDK framework ?

Comment: There is no FacebookSDK framework  when i make search in framework libraries.

Comment: you have to add FacebookSDK to overcome this issue .

Answer (score 0):

For ios6,no need to add FacebookSDK it has in-build library . ADD `Social.framework` and `Accounts.framework`.using `SLComposeViewController` you can share image,url,text.